# Can't write to Dalli Store from Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached, dalli

I use Rails 3.2.14, Ruby 2.1.2 and Memcached 1.4.13 on my Mac. I setup dalli as described here: https://github.com/mperham/dalli

Unfortunately trying Rails.cache.write(:foo, 1) returns false and thus Rails.cache.read(:foo) returns nil.

What am I missing to properly use dalli_store as cache_store in my rails application?

Answer (score 0):

had to start memcached server manually with memchached -vv. Works fine now